# Is it called "memory alignment" or "data alignment"?

Tags: c++, x86, terminology, memory-alignment

Sorry for this stupid question. I just want to know when we are talking about how data in memory should be aligned and stuff like that. Is this subject called "memory alignment" or "data alignment" or can I call it whatever I want?

Comment: Call it "data structure alignment" and everybody knows what you mean.

Comment: Sure, call it whatever you want, unless you want someone to know what you mean.

Comment: @Scott Hunter Call it whatever I want as in "memory alignment" and "data alignment" will both be fine.

Comment: @HansPassant, why add structures to the terminology? PODs may have alignment issues just as well

Answer (score 1):

In the context of programming, it's called [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Answer (score 0):

"Memory alignment" can refer to both data and code.  It's probably better to be specific and talk about data alignment or instruction alignment, depending on which you mean.  For concepts that refer to both, the term "memory alignment" is good, although you may find other people using it in ways that don't refer to both data and code.

Comment: Should we update the wiki to mention issues related to code alignment?